# How to satisfy .Net Framework 4.0 requirement when 4.6 is already installed

Tags: .net, windows-10, .net-framework-version, visualgdb

I'm trying to use https://visualgdb.com/ which allows for GCC based toolchain compilation within visual studio - however, it has a hardcoded requirement for .NetFramework 4.0. I have VS Community 2017 installed on windows 10, which includes .Net 4.5 and 4.6 as well as legacy 2.0 and 3.0 but no 4.0.

Is there some way to either force install 4.0, or to force **visualgdb** to accept 4.6 (it doesn't try to use it, just fails doing some sanity checks early on).

Their support hasn't been helpful so far.  Also, there is no C# code anywhere, but their system has some internal requirement for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to have the framework 4 targeting pack installed as an option when setting up Visual Studio.